# C: How to filter commands?

Tags: c

I was asked to write a program that operates on a given string. The commands come in the form of two letters followed by nothing, or an int(s) or string(s). The commands work on the given string (reversing it, multiplying it, replacing instances of a substring with another substring).

I'm pretty new to C and programming in general, and I have difficulty in recieving the commands themselves. How do I both make sure that the command I'm given is correct in both name and arguments? Will I need to use an array of functions (does that exist?) after I've found that the command I was given was correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend that you learn how to use [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/), which sounds perfect for what you want.

If the string is stored in the array `a`, you can use something like this to see if the two letters are "IA" followed by an int:

```
sscanf(a, "IA %d", &intVar);
```

If you want to check for the case of the letters "SA" followed by a string:

```
sscanf(a, "SA %s", &charArray);
```

The key here is checking the return value of `sscanf`, so you can know how many of the arguments were successfully assigned values from the format string. This means you can also add arguments for more strings, assuming that there's some maximum number of ints / strings that could follow the two letters.